# Not able to convert scientific notation to decimal in php

Tags: php

I am trying to convert scitntific notation to decimal. But the following codes not able to convert

```
$stringval = "1.356e-05";
$numericval = sscanf($stringval, "%f")[0];
echo $numericval; // 1.356E-05

(float) $stringval // 1.356E-05

(double) $stringval // 1.356E-05

$stringval + 0 // 1.356E-05
```

I get ouput as 1.356E-05 i want 0.00001356.
when i give `$stringval = "1.356e-04";` It is working but for `$stringval = "1.356e-05";` it is not working

Comment: I think you should try this number_format($stringval,8);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
printf('%.8f', floatval('1.356e-05'));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`number_format()`](https://secure.php.net/number_format) is what you are looking for.

```
$stringval = "1.356e-04";
$numericval = sscanf($stringval, "%f")[0];
echo number_format($numericval, 8);
```